# Accessing a public psql server in a kubernetes cluster

Tags: postgresql, azure, kubernetes

I have a PostgreSQL server running in azure with port no 5432, which is publically accessible. There is a Kubernetes cluster running several pods. I am trying to access the PostgresSQL server in a pod but It says the port is not open. although, on my personal machine, It is accessible.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

So Postgres is accessible from your machine but not from a pod? Does the pod have internet access? do you get an error ?

You can access the postgres locally in the kubernetes cluster:
if the pod is in the same namespace you can use  psql -h "svc name" where svc of the postgres pod.
If the pod is in a different namespace you need to use the full dns name
in this example the svc name psql is in the prod namesapce.
psql.prod.svc.cluster.local.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/